# Angular Routes Send Data To The Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I am designing a single page application in Angular and have been doing it all wrong! I'm currently re-doing it with routing, which means that instead of doing `$ajax` or `$http` calls to the server, I want to use something like this:

```
       .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : '/contentMore',
            controller  : 'contentController'
        });
```

My problem is with the `templateUrl`.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/contentMore",
    type: "GET", 
     data: {request:"Section_I_Part_1_Complete",part:"1"},
    success: function(data){
        $scope.robot.ajax = true;
        $scope.robot.sectionStayActiveI = false;
      theData = data;
      $scope.$apply();    
     $scope.html = theData; 
      $('#shyBox').mCustomScrollbar({
      theme:"dark"
      });     
      $scope.background.push("I");    
      }
  });
```

All of my content is served from the same url, `http://example.com/contentMore` and what is served is determined by the data that gets sent with it in the ajax request. If the templateUrl is just `/contentMore` without this data, then nothing will be served, so how do I pass this data?

Do I just encode the url or something? Also went the templateUrl is loaded, is this considered a form of an ajax request?

Thanks!

Comment: You should start by using ONLY `$http` and NOT `jQuery.ajax()` - When using `$http` angular "knows" when the request promise has been resolved - This will allow it to trigger a digest cycle and update the bindings in your app

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes thank you, I have learned this lol. But do I even have to use `$http` when using `templateUrl` in routing? My main issue now is that I have no routing so my users are hitting the back button and going to a completely different page.

Comment: You can dynamically serve the template using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) which adds extra functionality to the basic angular `$routeProvider`- [Read this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates) if @Chic's answer is not sufficient enought. And for your question about always  using `$http`- The answer is ALWAYS USE $http, jQuery is there only as a last resort and should only be used inside a directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templateUrl is for getting (usually static) html. The url should contain all of the information for what template you are trying to receive. Angular retrieves this content via an XHR request.

Comment: So I do encode the url or something? That's how a `GET` request works anyway when you send additional data correct? It just appends it to the url somehow? Is this the proper method?

Comment: Yeah, I would have the URL contain enough information to identify what template to show. Then when angular makes a `GET` request, your server will know what to return. The application I'm working on has static templates so the server just returns the file. But since you already a dynamic response url encoding is probably easiest